# Upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, network not working, eth0 state DOWN

Tags: networking

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, rebooted the machine, and my network cards aren't working. `ip a` tells me:

```
eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_code1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether ac:1f:...:5d brd ff:ff:...
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether ac:1f:...:5c brd ff:ff:...
```

`journalctl -u systemd-udevd -b` tells me:

```
eth0: Failed to process device, ignoring: File exists
```

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file says (line-breaks before ATTR added for display, not in actual file):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="ac:1f:...:5d",
 ATTR{div_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="ac:1f:...:5c",
 ATTR{div_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

So current my understanding is that somehow, during the upgrade, my network cards have got switched, and `eth0` became `eth1`, and `eth1` become `eth0`, and now they can't rename because the names are conflicting.

Is that understanding correct, and how can I fix it? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I added another rule to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to rename `eth0` to `eth2`, then renamed `eth1` to `eth0`, then rename `eth2` to `eth1` and this has corrected the issue: my networking and my machine is up again. But of course that's rather a 'hacky' solution, and I would rather work out how to have it configure correctly in the first place...

Comment: There's probably two solutions to this.  Either rename the cards back to how they were before they got switched (like you did) or edit the network config files to match the new card names.   For a stable solution, a udev rule matching mac address to card name would probably be best.

Comment: He did have udev rules to do that in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, but something (perhaps the machine's BIOS, perhaps the newer kernel in ubuntu 20.04 (unlikely), perhaps an updated firmware file for the NICs) switched the MAC addresses.  Network interfaces usually don't get names like eth0 and eth1 these days (for about 10 years now) without a udev rule renaming them from the consistent network device naming style (e.g. enp15s0)

Comment: It's most probably an ubuntu issue, I had similar stuff (renaming enp2s0 to eth0) during an upgrade to 20 by myself (comes in handy when trying to update remotely).